# Share local variables from super method in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a way to access local variables used in a parent function in Coffeescript?

For example, knowing the value of testLocal from class B:

```
class A
  constructor: ->
    @init()

  init: ->
    testLocal = 56


class B extends A

  init: ->
    super
    alert testLocal

new B()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `@` symbol in front of the references to `testLocal`

```
class A
  constructor: ->
    @init()

  init: ->
    @testLocal = 56


class B extends A

  init: ->
    super
    alert @testLocal

new B()
```

In your original example, the relevant javascript looks like this:

```
  A.prototype.init = function() {
    var testLocal;
    return testLocal = 56;
  };

  return A;

  B.prototype.init = function() {
    B.__super__.init.apply(this, arguments);
    return alert(testLocal);
  };
```

With the `@` added, you get this instead:

```
  A.prototype.init = function() {
    return this.testLocal = 56;
  };


  B.prototype.init = function() {
    B.__super__.init.apply(this, arguments);
    return alert(this.testLocal);
  };
```

`@` adds a `this.` to the references, moving the variable out of local scope, and into the coffeescript puesdo class.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I didn't want to do, cause that would defeat the local variable scope purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @mojarras It's a local varible that no longer exists as soon as it's scope ends. To access it in the descendand ctor you have to extend the scope. `@` accomplishes this, making it a property/field of the class rather then a local.

Comment: Yup, I guess there is no other way than to mark them with the @, I just thought there was some way to share those local variables. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @mojarras `local` has a specific lexical scope meaning. What you are asking for is the opposite of a local. You'd see this exact same restriction in *pretty much any other language* as well.